# Can you intercept a touch event from a child xml element

Tags: android, android-view, android-xml, android-gesture

I have a viewpager and I would like to intercept touch events on its parent container.
The xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:id="@+id/layoutContainer"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

since the view pager takes up the whole screen if try to attach a onTouchListener to the container with id "layoutContainer" nothing will ever fire.

I want to be able to detect vertical swipe gestures on the screen

```
private class MyGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

        return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

        Snap snap = snaps.get(targetPosition);

        return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        float deltaX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float deltaY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();

        if ((Math.abs(deltaX) < SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) || (Math.abs(velocityX) < SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)) {

        }
        else {

        }

        if ((Math.abs(deltaY) < SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE) || (Math.abs(velocityY) < SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY)) {

        }
        else {
            app.log("swipe up");
            //execute some code here
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Another thing I tried to do was attach a touch listener to the view pager and then manually pass the motion event to the gesture detector but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a containerview extends RelativeLayout , and override the onInterceptTouchEvent in this viewgroup.
like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            mDownX = event.getX();
            mDownY = event.getY();
            return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (Math.abs(event.getX() - mDownX) < Math.abs(event.getY() - mDownY)) { // Up and down around sliding distance is greater than sliding distance;
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```